# Record voice call

Tags: symbian, audio-recording

Are there any programs or libraries that will allow me to record phone calls on Symbian OS? Especially using Java/C++/Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own . Check out CCMRTest sample in 
http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Symbian_C%2B%2B_Example_Projects

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at web companies that provide voice related web services SaaS like Tropo for example (e.g. http://blog.tropo.com/tag/recording/)

Comment: I don't need such services. Just a local program which will record calls.

Comment: @Ockonal Did you get any resource? Even i'm also searching for the same.